# 401 Unauthorized error by eclipse while cloning from git repository hosted on Apache Http Server

Tags: eclipse, git

I have hosted git repository on Apache Http server and I have used Basic Authentication and  git (git-http-backend.exe).

I can clone, pull, push using command promt by providing username and password but
When,
 I tried to clone through eclipse (mars.1) is showing

401 Unauthorized

[image]

Below is my httpd.conf

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/Repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAliasMatch \
    "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
      info/refs | \
        objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
          [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
            pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
              git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
                    "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"  


# Authentication
<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    #Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Login"
    AuthUserFile "C:/Apache24/bin/gituserpass.git"
    Require user ensys
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>


<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-upload-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    #Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Login"
    AuthUserFile "C:/Apache24/bin/gituserpass.git"
    Require user ensys    
</LocationMatch>

<Directory />
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug that has beend adressed **[here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501000)**. Basically, the private git servers got broken following an update on Git that made it do a pre-verification of credentials (using stored or en-cache passwords). The password then gets *modified/removed*, and the final server (your git server in your case) throws a **401**.